# Update new table with specific select from other table MySql

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

This one is braking my head . Moving old articles rating for client from old DB to new DB where the only reference between them is first word which is separated by dash in article title.   I am able to pull the info I need by using SELECT but I cant figure out how to use the result to update the new table

table that needs to be updated

```
UPDATE 
newDB.newtable.rating
SET  newDB.newtable.rating.rating_count = oldvotes
```

the select that gives me the info on oldvotes

```
SELECT 
    oldvotes.votes AS oldvotes, old.title AS oldtitle,newtable.news_items.title as newtitle,newtable.news_items.id AS newID
FROM 
    oldDB.news_items AS old
INNER JOIN 
     oldDB.news_items.rating_count AS oldvotes 
ON 
     oldvotes.article_id = old.id
INNER JOIN 
      newDB.newtable.news_items
ON 
      newDB.newtable.news_items.title 
LIKE CONCAT
      (  '%', SUBSTRING_INDEX( old.title,  '- ', 1 ) ,  '%' )
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I understand correctly, you have in old.title something like thisisauniquekey-september-2012, and in news_items.title the value 'thisisauniquekey-somethingelse'.

You could select a key (a faster key than the title) and the oldvotes into a temporary table, say, `oldratings`, using the same query you run now:

```
SELECT news_items.keytobeusedonnewtable AS keyforrating, oldvotes.votes as oldvotes FROM etc.
```

Then you can run the update using `oldratings`:

```
UPDATE newDB.newtable.rating SET rating_value = oldvotes FROM
newDB.newtable.rating JOIN oldratings
    ON rating.keyforrating = oldvotes.keyforrating;
```

Comment: kinda but I don't know if you noticed, 4 tables are involved ,  
1. old news items
2. old rating
3. new news items 
4. new rating

Comment: In the first select, yes, I did notice. But it seems to me that you could extract, from the first SELECT, the information required to locate the row in the table you have to edit, new rating. Since you specified an UPDATE, I believe that you already have the new rating table, and only need to update its values?

Comment: More precisely, the newtable.news_items.id you have in your SELECT - that is an ID which is also used in the new ratings, is it not? To link the ratings with the news items?

Comment: yes , I have new tables , from rating , il try to explain query I need in words

select oldrating from old DB where old rating item id = old rating table article_id , Update new rating table row rating_count with old rating, where , newdb article title contains part of the title from olddb article title. I know is confusing

Comment: But the query which 'extracts all information' could extract the wanted rating and the news_item id, could it not? If it does, and that ID is good for the new rating table, why shouldn't it work?

Comment: is not good , I advise above , nothing else matches those article table except the part of title , example  OldTitle - old desc, OldTitile - new description , so I can patch them on on OldTitle-

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15584/discussion-between-lserni-and-benn)